# Get Active Smartpart from another smart part

Tags: scsf

I am working on customized smart client application. I want to know active smartpart from another smart part. As I am using command handler as per user demand One button "New" will be used for all forms. If I open more then one views/smartpart and click on new button this action get fired for all of smart part in workspace. How can I put check there so that New button action could be handled for only the one/view/smartpart which is active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WorkItem.Workspaces[WorkspaceNames.YourWorkspaceName].ActiveSmartPart`